# C# xdocument read from element and put the value into string

Tags: c#, copy, linq-to-xml

I have a problem.
This is the first time i work with a xml document in c#

I have a XML document like this:

```
  <root>
    <GLOBAL>
        <copy>@srcdir@c:\test1\test.txt, @destdir@C:\test1\test.txt</copy>
    </GLOBAL>
  </root>
```

Now i want to make an application in c# that loads the xml (done using xdocument), you chose an option (in this case global) and then it gets the copy element, and copie's the files listed in this element.

I have the copy function working, loading the xml is done, but getting the srcdir and destdir in an variable is a problem.

Any one which can help me getting on the right track?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Linq` to `Xml` you could do this.

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filepath);       
    var copyitems = doc.Descendants("GLOBAL")   // Read all descendants     
        .Select(s=> 
            {
                var splits = s.Value.Split(new string[] {"@srcdir@", "@destdir@"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); // split the string to separate source and destination.
                return new { Source = splits[0].Replace(",",""), Destination = splits[1].Replace(",","")};
            })
        .ToList();
```

Now you can read source and destination as...

```
    foreach(var copy in copyitems)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}- {1}", copy.Source, copy.Destination);
    }
```

**Output:**

```
c:\test1\test.txt - C:\test1\test.txt
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3oWyBo)

Comment: Thanks for the help. It is working very nice in your demo, but when i try this solution i get: Index was outside the bounds of the array. Any idea?

Comment: Found the problem, I think i can move on now. Thanks, will report back if im stuck again

Comment: Great, glad this solution helped you.

Comment: Hi, can you help me out again? I want to be able to have more copy lines in one decedent, how could i do this? Everytime i add one extra line i get this error: Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: So something like this: <test>
 <Copy>@SRCDIR@\test\test1.txt ,@KRQDIR@\test1\</Copy>
 <Copy>@SRCDIR@\test\test2.txt ,@KRQDIR@\test1\</Copy>
</test>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You should try to do something like this :

```
<copy src="c:\test1\test.txt" dest="C:\test1\test.txt"/>
```

And get attribut instead.

Comment: Yeah, it would be easier, but i have to edit about 4500 lines of code (the xml is already there)