# C# linq get all items in descendant and split the value

Tags: c#, linq, copy

Some time ago i asked the question how to read from a xml document and use the value (see [C# xdocument read from element and put the value into string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36865982/c-sharp-xdocument-read-from-element-and-put-the-value-into-string))

Now i have the following issue, the solution given in the last thread works, but only if i do this:

```
<root>
    <test>
        <Copy01>@SRCDIR@\test1 ,@INSTDIR@\test2</Copy01>
    </test>
</root>
```

but i want something like this:

```
<root>
    <test>
        <Copy01>@SRCDIR@\test1 ,@INSTDIR@\test2</Copy01>
        <Copy02>@SRCDIR@\test3 ,@INSTDIR@\test4</Copy02>
    </test>
</root
```

but with the following code in C#:

```
 var copyitems = doc.Descendants(param[1])

                        .Select(s =>

                    {
                        var splits = s.Value.Split(new string[] { "@SRCDIR@", "@INSTDIR@" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); // split the string to separate source and destination.
                        return new { Source = splits[0].Replace(",", ""), Destination = splits[1].Replace(",", "") };
                    })
                    .ToList();
```

Value of param[1] is "test" in this case
it only picks the first copy (copy01) and not the second one.

Any idea how to fix this?

Nick

Comment: What is the value of `param[1]`?

Comment: Sorry, that value is "test" in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to select the child elements of the `test` elements. You can use `SelectMany` and the `Elements` methods to do it like this:

```
var copyitems =
    doc.Descendants("test") //Select all "test" elements
    .SelectMany(x => x.Elements()) //Select all children of all "test" elements
    .Select(s => 
    {
        //...
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, can you help with one more thing? Now i get the value of the descedants (in this case from test) Now i only want the name of the descedant (so you will get as output "copy" and not the source and destination)

Comment: You should be able to select `s.Name`.